# como preguntar o comprobar si una consulta trae un dato especifico

Tags: sql, vb.net

tengo este codigo sencillo para ingresar a un sistema quisiera saber si mediante este mismo codigo hay alguna forma de preguntar que si el tipo de usuario que selecciono es administrador,etc. para realizar acciones determinadas?

este es el codigo:

```
Private Sub btningresar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btningresar.Click
    Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SAMUELSUSANA; Initial catalog=poovb;integrated security=true")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    'Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    'Dim dt As DataTable

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from Usuario where Usuario='" & Me.txtusuario.Text & "'and Clave='" & Me.txtcontraseña.Text & "'and Tipo= '" & Me.cbtipo.Text & "'", conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If (dr.HasRows = True) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido al Sistema Señor/a..." + txtusuario.Text)
            Me.Hide()
            MenuPrincipal.Show()

        ElseIf (dr.HasRows = False) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario y/o Contraseña Erronea, Por favor intente de nuevo.")
            txtusuario.Clear()
            txtcontraseña.Clear()
            cbtipo.Text = ""
            txtusuario.Focus()
            conteo = conteo + 1
            If (conteo = 3) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Ha alcanzado el limite de intentos, Vuelva a intentarlo mas tarde con datos correctos.")
                Application.Exit()

            End If


        End If
    Catch Exoledb As Exception
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu tabla de Usuarios contiene el nivel de acceso seria de la siguiente forma:

```
If (dr.HasRows = True) Then
        //Leemos el tipo de acceso
            Dim accesso AS [TIPODEDATODELACCESO] = Conver.To[TIPODEDATO](dr[NOMBRECAMPODETABLA])
            MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido al Sistema Señor/a..." + txtusuario.Text)
            Me.Hide()
            MenuPrincipal.Show()
```

donde [TIPODEDATODELACCESO] es como venga definido en tu tabla de la BD el campo ya sea int, decimal, etc. y el convert seria de acuerdo al tipo de dato que necesites convertir el objeto.

NOMBRECAMPODETABLA seria el campo de la tabla de la BD que contiene el nivel de acceso

Por ejemplo: Asumiendo que nuestra tabla contenga el campo permiso tipo int que defina el nivel de acceso seria:

```
Dim acceso as int = Convert.ToInt32(dr["permiso"])
```

**Nota: Tu consulta es propensa a inyeccion sql considera cambiarla por una consulta parametrizada**

Comment: gracias lo tomare en cuenta